# Displaying data with MySQL and PHP for my e-commerce website

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I have a database that I am pulling data from. On my original PHP script I run the query and fetch the data, then echo it out, but for some reason this second script I have is not working. The query's are identical on the each page, so I'm not sure why it is tell me this, but it's saying my `$price` variable is not defined.

This is the code that is not working properly:

```
$cartoutput = "";
$cartTotal="";
if(!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
    $cartoutput = "<font>Your Cart is currently empty.</font>";
}else{
    $i=0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem WHERE id='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
            if (!$result) {
            printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));// Displays the error that mysql will generate if syntax is not correct.
            exit();
            }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $product_name = $row["name"];
                $price = $row["price"];
        }   
        $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;

        $i++;
        $cartoutput .="<font>Item $i &nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;</font>"; $cartoutput .= $each_item['item_id'] . $each_item['quantity'] . "<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

More specifically, the line:

```
$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
```

is causing the problem. Like I said before, I have another PHP script that is being used the same way, and doesn't give me any problems. Doesn't it look like `$price`is defined in the WHILE LOOP? I've tried coding it differently, and nothing is working. My end goal is to just echo`$cartTotal`, but I can't do that because I'm getting the error $price is not defined?

Comment: Can you share the output of 'var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result));` and `var_dump($row);` inside `while` loop ?

Comment: what does print_r($row) show you?

Comment: agreed. make sure your `while` loop is actually being executed by printing inside of it.

Comment: < 1 and <= 0 is exactly the same thing when dealing with integers.

Comment: When I print_r($row) I don't get anything at all. I'm not sure why.

Comment: do you get any results if you do the query directly in mysql command line?

Comment: Is there a danger of re-inventing the wheel here (although I accept that sometimes wheels need re-inventing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$price` is defined in a while loop, so its context ends in the while loop. At the time you are trying to use it it does not exist anymore. Even if that was allowed, you would only read the last value of `$price`. You want to do the entire calculation in the loop. Change it to this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $product_name = $row["name"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
    $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
    $i++;
    $cartoutput .="<font>Item $i &nbsp;&nbsp; - &nbsp;</font>"; $cartoutput .= $each_item['item_id'] . $each_item['quantity'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and now I don't have an error, but the cartTotal is not displayed at all. It just removes everything.

Comment: Most likely your while loop is not executed. Can you try to add an echo "TEST"; in your while loop and see if that gets printed on screen? Check the source code of the page, not just what you see rendered in browser. (Right click, view source)

Comment: And also add echo mysqli_num_rows($result); just before the while loop.

Comment: I just noticed the "LIMIT 1". You don't even need the while actually, you can just call mysql_fetch_array once to get your result.

Comment: You're right. the while loop is not being executed. echo "TEST"; did not populate anything on the screen. echo mysqli_num_rows($result); produced 0. @fabien Warniez

Comment: Is $item_id an int? If so, then remove the quotes around $item_id in the query. Also, print $item_id to make sure it looks like what you are expecting.

Comment: Hey thank you @Fabien Warniez my $item_id was pointed to my database item_name from the form on the first page. Everything is working as it should, now. Thanks again!